# Round and square brackets in one line python code

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar, one-liner

I know it's not worth writing like that, but still, I'm very interested in what this tip is called and where can I find out more about it?

```
d = {}
for i in range(10):
    ({}, d)[i%2][i] = i ** 2
```

I understand what it's doing, but I didn't find the name, no matter how I tried to Google it.

Comment: I've never heard of a name for this construct.

Comment: @Barmar My bad deleted the comment.

Comment: *Round and square brackets in one line* - in that case you may call it "dictionary in a tuple"

Comment: It's called "barely readable code". Also, what's the point in assigning to an anonymous dict `{}` that only exists for as long as it takes to make the assignment?

Comment: FWIW, that's an unnecessarily convoluted way of writing an `if` statement, and it _runs slower!_ (3.88 µs vs 2.03 µs on my computer)

Comment: This is also an error waiting to happen, because neither `{}[i%2]` nor `d[i%2]` is a `dict`.

Comment: @chepner I think the "point" is to only assign to `d[i]` when `i` is odd. Of course, there are numerous better ways to do it.

Comment: Really interesting way to mimic `_` for dictionaries. It's much less readable than an if statement checking for evenness but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: I can't imagine writing code like this outside an obfuscated code contest.

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is "kludge"

Comment: I'd call this flunking the class.

Comment: I guess it's just "indexing an anonymous tuple, and then indexing the (possibly anonymous) dictionary that results". But honestly it would be much better written as `d = {i: i**2 for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0}`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I think you're right, it sounds the most logical, thank you

Comment: @Barmar I wrote specifically that this is BAD code, but I was interested in learning the construction itself.

Comment: I know. And I answered that in my first comment. There's no need for names for things that no one actually writes.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, I understand, it's more of a sporting interest. I also met something similar on preliminary tests in some companies

Comment: @Barmar xD yeah, i think u're right